# How to reload javascript modules for Firefox extension development?

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, javascript, firefox-extensions

Currently, when I develop a Firefox extension that uses [JavaScript Modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Javascript_modules) (JSM), then I have to disable the extension -> restart Firefox -> enable the extension -> restart Firefox in order to execute any modifications that I make to to a JSM file.

Is there a better way, such that I can reload the JSM with only a single restart of Firefox perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This thread](http://groups.google.com/group/mozilla.dev.extensions/browse_thread/thread/116702878c962a64) offers a better solution.

set these prefs:

- `nglayout.debug.disable_xul_fastload` to true
- `nglayout.debug.disable_xul_cache` to true

As described on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Setting_up_extension_development_environment

Comment: This is not a good answer. You should have provided at least basic information from the linked webpage.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox implemented a simple feature for that, Available on

> about:debugging

Enable add-on debugging, load your add-on temporarily and voila you have a button available for reloading it as you make modification to JS/CSS/Etc.